# Caching data before presenting popover

Tags: iphone

I have a main controller, and a popover that gets presented from the main controller.  My main controller passes an array to my popover.  In my viewDidLoad of my popover controller, I take that array, get the image and text data for that entry and put it into an NSDictionary.  I do this because I need to resize my pictures for my UITableView to be presented in the popover.  It works fine, however, since I now have an NSArray of NSDictionary in my popover, every time I bring up my popover, since this code is in the viewDidLoad, it gets created each time.  It seems like an expensive operation since there is a bit of lag in presenting the popover to begin with.  Is there a way I can cache the data somewhere once it's loaded once?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you create it in your main controller and pass it as a parameter to your popover?

Comment: I'm trying to understand this more to see how this would work.  Right now when a button in the UIToolBar gets selected, based on a selection in a UISegmentControl (with 3 segments), I get data for the popover to be presented.  So would I need 3 different variables, that could get populated lazily, and then always just use that information when needed?